# Static element that remains between navigation transitions (React Native)

Tags: react-native

I have a multi-screen form flow. I would like to display a progress bar at the top of all screens.

Currently, scene transitions bring in a new progress bar element and cover the old one.

I am looking for a way to have the progress bar remain static while the new scene slides in.

Answer (score 2):

The code for what @MattAft is trying to say would be:

```
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <ProgressBar props={your.props}/>
        <AppNavigator />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Both the ProgressBar and the AppNavigator would be components that you made. The AppNavigator component will have inside it the Navigator component that you are currently using.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to move the progress bar out of the navigator to prevent the scene transitions from affecting it and to keep it static. If you're using redux, you can create an action that updates the progress bar as you transition through the scenes.